# Echo SKU to product page (from Mageworx Advanced Product Options Suite) M2.3

Tags: magento2.3, sku

Not sure if anyone can help, but basically I am trying to find a way to echo the SKU of the selected custom option (using Mageworx Advanced Product Options Suite) to the product page, either in the current SKU position or underneath the last custom option.

Just wondering if anyone has any solutions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

we are using Magento 2.3

Many thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

We've just bumped into your mention of one of our top products here. Unfortunately, the functionality is unavailable at this very moment. But I've passed along your question to the dev team. They find it extremely interesting. As a result, the functionality is included within the roadmap and planned to be added within the next extension update. =)

Thanks for sharing!

Regards,
MageWorx Team

Comment: Hey Mageworx, thank you for your reply, I am just checking in to see if this feature is in the new 2.20 version? Many thanks Richard